# Why do these two grep commands produce different results?

Tags: regex, grep

```
$ grep "^底线$" query_20220922  | wc -l
95701
$ grep -iF "底线" query_20220922  | wc -l
796591
```

Shouldn't the count be exactly the same? I want to count the exact match  of the string.

Comment: first of all, you can use `-c` to count number of matching lines (you'll need `-o` and piping to `wc -l` if you can have more than one match per line)... second, can you explain your reasons as to why you expect these two commands to give same result?

Comment: This might help: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

`-F` matches a fixed string anywhere in a line. `^xyz$` matches lines which contain "xyz" exactly (nothing else).

You are looking for `-x`/`--line-regexp` and not `-F`/`--fixed-strings`.

To match lines which contain your search text exactly, without anything else and without interpreting your search text as regular expression, combine the two flags: `grep -xF 'findme' file.txt`.

Also, case-insensitive matching (`-i`) can match more lines too than case-sensitive matching (the default).

Answer (score 0):

No, they do different things. The first uses a regular expression to search for "底线" alone on an input line (`^` in a regular expression means beginning of line, and `$` means end of line).

The second searches for the string anywhere on an input line. The `-i` flag does nothing at all here (it selects case-insensitive matching, but this is not well-defined for CJK character sets, so basically a no-op) and `-F` says to search literally (which makes the search faster for internal reasons, but doesn't change the semantics of a search string which doesn't contain any regex metacharacters).

It should be easy to see how they differ. For a large input file, it might be a bit challenging to find the differences if they are not conveniently mixed; but for a quick start, try

```
diff -u <(grep -m5 "^底线$" query_20220922) <(grep -m5Fi "底线" query_20220922)
```

where `-m5` picks out the first five matches. (Try a different range, perhaps with `tail`, if the differences are all near the end of the file, for example.)

Tangentially, you usually want to replace the pipe to `wc -l` with `grep -c`; also,you might want to try `grep -Fx "底线"` as a faster alternative to the first search.

Comment: So "grep -Fx" will do exact string match, "grep -x" will do exact regular expression match, and "grep -Fxic" will count the case-insensive exact string matches. Right?

Comment: Also, I tried "grep -xFi nba hot_query_20220922 | wc -l" and "grep -xFic nba query_20220922, but the count numbers are different. Why is that?

Comment: Looks like the file names are different.